# How can I insert a certain text into already existing formulas with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace the text of an existing formula with other text, but the code is just working for the change from x to y and not for x to z as it shows the runtime error 1004.

Does anybody have an idea why?

```
Sub MySub()
Dim x As String
Dim y As String
Dim z As String
Dim i As Integer

x = "$S:$S"
y = "$R:$R"
z = "$R:$R;"" <= ""&J$2;[activated201902.xlsx]riskmodel_new!$R:$R;"" > ""&I$2)"

For i = 1 To 10
Cells(i, "E").FormulaLocal = Replace(Cells(i, "E").FormulaLocal, x, y)
Cells(i, "J").FormulaLocal = Replace(Cells(i, "J").FormulaLocal, x, z)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `i` at the time of error and what is the formula in that cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In formula strings in VBA you will have to double the quotation marks, so you were on the right path:

```
Dim x As String
Dim y As String
Dim z As String
Dim i As Integer

x = "$S:$S"
y = "$R:$R"
z = "$R:$R;"""" <= """"&J$2;[activated201902.xlsx]riskmodel_new!$R:$R;"""" > """"&I$2)"

For i = 1 To 10
Cells(i, "E").FormulaLocal = Replace(Cells(i, "E").FormulaLocal, x, y)
Cells(i, "J").FormulaLocal = Replace(Cells(i, "J").FormulaLocal, x, z)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the quick response, but it still shows the same error

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and looked at the variables to see what you would create is an actual formula?

Comment: You could split a string and then concatenate the split strings with a new string. However, why not just do something like `Cells(i, "J").FormulaLocal = "=IF()..."`?

Comment: Yeah got it right, it was a problem with the variable. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help